# basic understanding of nmap

Tags: nmap

ok so i heard nmap is illegal in some countries, similar to going around and checking the door handle around the neighborhood to see if intrusion is possible.

if i use nmap like

```
 nmap -0 -sS 192.168.1.1/24
```

am i scanning the entire network from my isp for everything in .1.1/24 range
or am i just scanning within my gateway which is 192.168.1.1

i ran this 192.168.1.1/24 but then stopped myself and ran a nmap -sS -O 192.168.1.1XX/24 on my ip and it came up everything that was on my network

Answer (score 3):

```
nmap -O -sS 192.168.1.1/24
```

`192.168.1.1/24` Means that you are scanning the network `192.168.1.0` with a netmask of `255.255.255.0`.  That is what the `/24` at the end means, it is also called CIDR notation.  That means that only the IPs from `192.168.1.1` thru `192.168.1.254` are scanned.  Nothing outside of your network will be scanned at all.

I use the Online IP Subnet Calculator all the time to see what IP addresses belong to what range.  Look at the Mask Bits and that is what the `/24` at the end means.

http://www.subnet-calculator.com/

Site with CIDR notation:  http://www.subnet-calculator.com/cidr.php

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to learn terminology to read `nmap` properly.

The `192.168.1.0` is *network ID*. It refers to your local network, and every interface (this is also important - you can have multiple interfaces on same machine) that connects to that network will have address that start with `192.168.0.xxx`.It's not scanning outside of your router, so you're not scanning your ISP (and I recommend that you avoid doing that).

Depending on the configuration of your router, network can contain different number of hosts. If you say `/24` means you have 256 hosts on the network (this is because each IP address when converted to binary will be 32 bits in length, and we can vary last 8 bits, so those first 24 bits are not changing). When you perform scan like that, `nmap` also will confirm how many hosts it scanned:

```
OS detection performed. Please report any incorrect results at https://nmap.org/submit/ .
Nmap done: 256 IP addresses (3 hosts up) scanned in 202.14 seconds
```

`nmap` doesn't actually know your network configuration. Use `ip addr` to find out which exact CIDR-style addressing to use. For example, I have:

```
$ ip -4 -o addr show                                                                                                     
1: lo    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo\       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: wlan7    inet 192.168.0.101/24 brd 192.168.0.255 scope global dynamic wlan7\       valid_lft 63435sec preferred_lft 63435sec
```

Second, you have two examples there. Once ending with `.0` and one ending with `.1xx`. As far as `nmap` is concerned , it's the same thing. From `man nmap`:

> For example, 192.168.10.0/24 would scan the 256
>          hosts between 192.168.10.0 (binary: 11000000 10101000 00001010 00000000) and 192.168.10.255 (binary: 11000000
>          10101000 00001010 11111111), inclusive.  192.168.10.40/24 would scan exactly the same targets.